# What is the best place in code for the connectionstring and to migrate the database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, migration, database-migration

I was creating a Web API with .NET Core, using Entity Framework Core. When I was setting up the project I realized I had two methods with a connectionstring in the `Startup` class. The `ConfigureServices` en `Configure` method.

The `ConfigureServices` was to be able to create a migration of the models.

The `Configure` was to 'push' the migrations to the database.

I tried to make the `DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>` a field to access it in both methods so I'd only have one place where the connectionstring is set. But probably I wasn't implementing this method too well, because the Update-Database command failed with:

> ERROR: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Then I thought "*The Context also has an* [`OnConfiguring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onconfiguring?view=efcore-3.1) *method, which is just called for each instance of the context that is created. Maybe I should put the* `Database.Migrate()` *function there?*"

Now I'm confused where to instantiate the connectionstring in a multi-tier architecture, how do you do it? And have you set the connectionstring on one place, or multiple? Some arguments maybe?

And where to migrate the database? Is that better done in the `OnConfiguring` method of the `DbContext` class?

**My solution**:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private readonly DbContextOptionsBuilder<FactVoiceContext> _dbContextOptionsBuilder;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FactVoiceContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(Configuration["DATABASE_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Necessary for migrations.. 
        services.AddDbContext<FactVoiceContext>( ctx =>
            ctx.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DATABASE_CONNECTIONSTRING"]));
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //Just to push migration to database TODO: needs to be better
        using (var context = new FactVoiceContext(_dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            context.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

**This didn't work**:
Database provider error

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Necessary for migrations.. 
    services.AddDbContext<FactVoiceContext>( ctx => ctx = _dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I noticed the context instantiation is created multiple times in my application lifecycle, means that isn't probably the best place to do the migration.

Comment: It is not clear what problem are your trying to solve. Don't you have your connectionstring stored in the appsettings.json file?

Comment: As you can see I have `Configuration["DATABASE_CONNECTIONSTRING"]`, but the thing is where am I going to tell the database to use that string? In the project `Startup`, maybe the `dbContext` itself or any other place?